# Add Text to input On Click

Tags: javascript

I want to type **kappa** in input on image click. I have [this code](http://bit.ly/1OlJ7KW) but it seems like it doesn't work...

```js
document.getElementById("kappa").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('usermsg');
    text.value = (text.innerHTML + ' kappa ');
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="kappa"><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' width='100px'></a>
<br>
<input type="text" id="usermsg">
```

Where did I made a mistake? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `value` instead of `text`:

```
document.getElementById("kappa").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('usermsg');
    text.value = (text.value + ' kappa ');
    return false;
});
```

And give a `return false` to make it not follow the link.

**Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjELxJ**

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

```
    document.getElementById("kappa").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById("usermsg").value = "kappa";
    });
```